# i have 2 dates and i have to get data between these dates my query is as follows

Tags: stored-procedures

```
   @trn_no varchar(20)= null,
    @from_date nvarchar(50)= null,
    @to_date nvarchar(50)= null
    AS
    BEGIN
        select * from [dbo].[vw_POD]
        where @trn_no is null 
           or [trn_no]=@trn_no 
           and @from_date is null or [trn_dt] between @from_date and @to_date
    END
```

when i search data between dates i get data of all the dates in the table what is wrong in the above code

Comment: so what's the problem now? Specify the database you are using.

Comment: For thy question to be worthy this mighty forum, thy shall [format and pose that like you write a wiki article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ok - my godly voiced english might be off a little ...

Comment: You're mixing or's and and's in your where statement. you should probably add some brackets or its likely not doing what you intended